# How do I register multiple events in jquery widget spinner

Tags: jquery

I am trying not to write the same function over and over. I have tried to list jquery selectors in the $(1, 2, 3).on(). but it only executes on the first.

```
var spinnerApt1X, spinnerApt1Y, spinnerApt2X, spinnerApt2Y;

function popSpinPtEditor(pt) {
  spinnerApt1X = $('#sectorEditorApt1XScroll').spinner({ min: 0});
  spinnerApt1X.spinner( 'value', pt.p1.x );
  spinnerApt1Y = $('#sectorEditorApt1YScroll').spinner({ min: 0});
  spinnerApt1Y.spinner( "value", pt.p1.y );
  spinnerApt2X = $('#sectorEditorApt2XScroll').spinner({ min: 0});
  spinnerApt2X.spinner( "value", pt.p2.x );
  spinnerApt2Y = $('#sectorEditorApt2YScroll').spinner({ min: 0});
  spinnerApt2Y.spinner( "value", pt.p2.y );
}

var spinPtObjAr = [spinnerApt1X, spinnerApt1Y, spinnerApt2X, spinnerApt2Y];

//this is the function I need help with.
$().add(  (function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < spinPtObjAr.length; i++) {
    var spin = spinPtObjAr[i]; 
  }
return spin
})()).on(
"spinstop", function(){
  console.log($(this).spinner('value'));
});
```

Comment: I changed the function to within the for loop and passed the array item in. Simple, should not have asked the question

Comment: Please provide explanation of what all this code should accomplish

Comment: also where will `popSpinPtEditor()` be called? Your array is full of undefined variables currently

Answer (score 1):

To transform an array of individual jQuery collections to a single jQuery collection, use Array#reduce() as follows :

```
$superCollection = arrayOfCollections.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    prev.add(current);
}, $());
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pt84ua4t/)**

Note: The order of the elements in `$superCollection` will be *document order* regardless of the order in which they were added. The [documentation for `add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) includes a good explanation of order issues.

In this particular case, you would do something like this :

```
var spinnerApt1X, spinnerApt1Y, spinnerApt2X, spinnerApt2Y, 
    allSpinners;

function popSpinPtEditor(pt) {
    spinnerApt1X = $('#sectorEditorApt1XScroll').spinner({ min: 0});
    spinnerApt1X.spinner( 'value', pt.p1.x );
    spinnerApt1Y = $('#sectorEditorApt1YScroll').spinner({ min: 0});
    spinnerApt1Y.spinner( "value", pt.p1.y );
    spinnerApt2X = $('#sectorEditorApt2XScroll').spinner({ min: 0});
    spinnerApt2X.spinner( "value", pt.p2.x );
    spinnerApt2Y = $('#sectorEditorApt2YScroll').spinner({ min: 0});
    spinnerApt2Y.spinner( "value", pt.p2.y );
    var spinnerArray = [spinnerApt1X, spinnerApt1Y, spinnerApt2X, spinnerApt2Y];
    allSpinners = spinnerArray.reduce(function(prev, current) {
        prev.add(current);
    }, $());
}
```

There's nothing wrong with this approach but more conventionally, you would select all the elements with a single jQuery selector *before* applying `spinner()`, then work with the collection thus formed to invoke/initialize `spinner()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at building a collection of these elements in the beginning.

A common class added to them all will cut down needing to use all the individual ID's in the selector. Data attributes can be used to define the properties they reference

```
<element id ="sectorEditorApt1XScroll" class="my-spinner" data-pt="p1" data-axis="x">
```

Then you can store a collection using a single class selector and do all your initialization in a simple loop

```
var $spinners = $('.my-spinner').on("spinstop", function(){
  console.log($(this).spinner('value'));
});

function popSpinPtEditor(pt) {
   $spinners.each(function(){
       var ptProps = $(this).data(); 
       $(this).spinner({min:0}.spinner( 'value', pt[ptProps.pt][ptProps.axis] );
   });
}
```

It is rare that you need to build your own arrays of jQuery elements, since jQuery does that internally based on selector used

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Teaching me about jquery collections makes this post well worth my time.

Comment: `$(selector)` always creates array of elements ... even if non found, then length is `0`. If one found it is still in an array at index `0`

Answer (score 0):

```
  function popSpinPtEditor(pt, collection) {
  var ptAr = [pt.p1.x, pt.p1.y, pt.p2.x, pt.p2.y, pt.cp1.x, pt.cp1.y, pt.cp2.x, pt.cp2.y];
 collection.each(function(i){
     var ptProps = $(this).data();
     $(this).spinner({min:0}).spinner( 'value', ptAr[i] );
  });

  collection.on("spinstop", function(){
    console.log($(this).spinner('value'));
  });
}

var pt = curve(), collection = $('.sectEditSpin');
popSpinPtEditor(pt, collection);
```

You helped me turn 50 lines of code into 10.

Comment: Getting the line count down is good but this solution relies on the hard-coded `ptAr ` being congruent with the `collection` passed to the function. With @charlietfl's idea to encode the data as data-items in the HTML, then [lack of] congruence will never be an issue.

Comment: Yes, html passing element specific data fields made this easier and more decoupled.